# Sed search replace pattern (bash)

Tags: bash, search, replace, sed, design-patterns

Here is some sample text I'm using with sed (in bash, centos). I've broken the text into lines to make it easier to read. **But the text below is usually all on one line.**

> some text
>   (Abc_3.7|*AUTODETECT*|"}{\fldrslt
>   \plain \f2\fs20\cf2 3:7}}\plain
>   \f2\fs20
>
> Xyz_3.16|*AUTODETECT*|"}{\fldrslt
>   \plain \f2\fs20\cf2 16}}\plain
>   \f2\fs20 more text,
>
> Qr_3.11|*AUTODETECT*|"}{\fldrslt
>   \plain \f2\fs20\cf2 11}}\plain
>   \f2\fs20 something

**I want to strip from each entry:** |*AUTODETECT*|"}{\fldrslt \plain \f2\fs20\cf2 3:7}}

The text between **\plain and }}** will vary, so I need to select everything.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
s/|AUTODETECT|\"}{\\fldrslt \\plain .*}}/ /g;
```

**The problem.** I **expect** the results to be:

```
Abc_3.7 \plain \f2\fs20 Xyz_3.16 \plain \f2\fs20 more text, Qr_3.11 \plain \f2\fs20 something
```

But the **actual results** are:

```
Abc_3.7 \plain \f2\fs20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` is greedy and matches everything from the first data after 'plain' up to the last pair of close braces, including the other auto-detects etc.  You need a more refined (less greedy) pattern:

```
sed 's/|AUTODETECT|"}{\\fldrslt \\plain [^}]*}}/ /g' "$@"
```

The '`[^}]*`' part matches an arbitrary sequence of anything except '}' (and newline).

---

If the script needs to go in a file, then the sed script file contains:

```
s/|AUTODETECT|"}{\\fldrslt \\plain [^}]*}}/ /g
```

and the invocation becomes:

```
sed -f sed.script "$@"
```

Basically, everything except the single quotes go into the script file.  One of the advantages of using single quotes is that there is less to worry about with escapes.  You only run into any problems when the script has to contain single quotes.

Comment: Wow, thank you, works great. How would I modify your code to put it into my .sed file? My experience with sed files so far is it doesn't like quotes...